# How to integrate a Lottie library with android project that doesn't support AndroidX?

Tags: android, lottie

I'm trying to integrate Lottie animation library version 3.4.0 and this version only supports Android X.

How can I integrate with this version without Android X migrating?

Comment: Use a version that doesn't require AndroidX

Comment: @Zun I tried that but the version that doesn't require AndroidX is too old is 2.7.0 and the animation requires the new version

Comment: There's no valid reason to NOT upgrade to AndroidX so I guess it's time for you to move on as well! Should only take a few minutes

Comment: @Zun we cannot upgrade to android X right now because there are a lot of libraries doesn't support android X yet

Comment: `android.enableJetifier: When this flag is set to true, the Android plugin automatically migrates existing third-party libraries to use AndroidX dependencies by rewriting their binaries. The flag is false by default if it is not specified.`. Don't blame AndroidX but yourself! Read the docs

Comment: @Zun I didn't blame androidX and I already tried all of these solutions.  :)